# Add image css field in content type

Tags: theming, media

I want to add an image css field in one of my content types. Drupal provides an "alt" and an "title" field for the image, but now I need to add a css field too.

Im using the image on a view, and I know I can add css there, but I want to be able to add special css for single images.

Is there a module or something, which makes it possible to add an css field in my content type? thanks.

Comment: You can either use the Media suite to capture fields related to media (as media are entities and are fieldable), find a module that has an image formatter that adds a "class" attribute that lets you add classes, or you can preprocess the image in your theme and add the class attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [Field Formatter Class](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_formatter_class) module which allows to add a CSS class to any field in `Content Type -> Manage Display`.

Of course, first you must implement your CSS class in your CSS file, then add it to the image field through `Manage Display`. Do not forget to clear the cache to get the results shown.

**EDIT:** I didn't notice you want your CSS style to be applied individually. Perhaps adding a new field for CSS class, then adding it to Field Formatter Class through [Token](https://www.drupal.org/project/token) module. Not sure whether this is feasible or not.